# How can I POST a form in AJAX with JSON encoded form values

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

On 'success' I need to submit `data` to PayPal. I know that `$.post('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', data);` is wrong because I need it to submit as if that were the form action, going to the PayPal page with the form values. All of the data is stored and properly formatted in the return JSON data. I checked it with `alert(data.cmd)`. I just don't know how to emulate an HTML POST action from here.

```
function process(plan_id) {
        var data = {'plan_id' : plan_id};
        $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "process_paypal.php",
                data: data,
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (data) { 
                alert(data.cmd);
                    $.post('https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr', data);
            },
             error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
                console.log(arguments); 
                alert(jqXHR + '-' + textStatus + '-' + errorThrown);
                return false;        
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Why not just handle the processing and submission in your php file, then collect and return the paypal response to your application?

Comment: Yes, I thought about that but I need this page to return an error if there's a problem updating the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to serialize your data using [$.serialize()](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) before sending it onto PayPal like this:

```
var data = {'plan_id' : plan_id};
$.ajax({
    ...
    data: $(data).serialize(),
    ...
});
```

By serializing the data you are converting it from an object to an encoded string which the PayPal service can read.

I hope this helps!

Comment: The process_paypal.php has all of the form data in it. I am only passing a variable for the option the user selected.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert json object to parameter string like key1=value1&key2=value2.. by following way

```
var result = decodeURIComponent($.param(data));
```

Then you can pass this result to paypal

```
$.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    ...
    data: result,
    ...
});
```

Comment: So this would go in the `success` block? `success: function (data) { 
             var result = decodeURIComponent($.param(data));
             type:'POST',
             url: 'https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr',
             data: result,
             success: function (data) { 
             
             }` How do I get the actual page to jump to PayPal as if the form were submitted more conventionally (HTML).

Comment: didn't get you exactly 'conventionally HTML' ?? ajax form submit is same as html form submit but difference only ajax is asynchronous.

Comment: I got 'conventional' HTML but the behavior is AJAX because the PayPal page is not loaded. I guess I have to submit a <form> from within the HTML via AJAX/Jquery in order for this to work?